# How can I optimize a switch statement on the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

So, I have a piece of Javascript code that's like

```
switch (n)
{
case 1:
// ...
case 2:
// ...
case 3:
// ...
case 4:
// ...
default: 
// never happens
}
```

However, I realize there's a problem because there will be a redundancy in checking `n` against `1` and `3` because if the first bit of `1` is off then `3` doesn't even need to be checked; likewise, if the first bit of `2` is on then `4` doesn't even need to be checked. How can I optimize this procedure? I need fast code because this logic is part of a game that runs very fast.

Comment: cpus don't compare individual bits when comparing numbers. they compare ALL of the bits AT ONCE. You are optimizing the entirely wrong thing.

Comment: How many cases in total?

Comment: Well, Dr. Knuth, the runtime has more efficient ways of interpreting a `switch` statement than even you would know.

Comment: I'd be a little surprised if modern engines didn't optimize this automatically to jump directly to the proper case, as long as it could determine that `n` is always a number.

Comment: How many cases are there - just four? I believe this cannot be optimized the way you describe it in JavaScript.

Comment: @cookiemonster compilers/interpreters have been doing that since basically forever.

Comment: I'd start by killing off the default case since you have declared that it will never be reached. (Only half-serious.)

Comment: @Pointy: Right, that's why it would surprise me if this wasn't already optimized. Is "jump table" the correct term?

Comment: you need to break after a successful case. or use an object lookup instead of a switch if you just need a 1:1 conversion

Comment: Have you looked into making your game ASM.js compliant?

Comment: @cookiemonster that's what I've always called it but I'm old and really lazy about terminology :)

Comment: You seem to have some very fundamental misunderstandings of what optimization is about. I suggest you concentrate solely on algorithmic optimizations until you get a few more years of experience.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array

```
myCommand[n]
```

with command objects as elements.

Comment: You've verified this to be faster? Not saying it isn't, but since JS Arrays are objects, they can be highly optimized under certain circumstances, and not under others. And then function calls require overhead as well *(though the OP may be invoking functions in a similar manner, can't tell)*.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is interpreted, so any optimization you attempt to do will be slower than the optimizations of the JavaScript interpreter, which will be compiled and run faster.

Just don't worry about it.

Comment: This is wrong in general. Please explain your answer.

Comment: I'm not understanding the *"JavaScript is interpreted, so..."* part. How does it being interpreted help?

Comment: @cookiemonster Because interpreted languages usually run slower than compiled ones

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying, but I don't know if I necessarily agree with such a broad statement. After all, the switch statement is interpreted too. I think the OP is asking if there's any construct or approach to the problem that would have better optimization than a switch.

Comment: I don't think this answer was phrased optimally, but it's really a great point - micro-optimizations in your JavaScript source code *might* help today, but tomorrow some whiz working on the V8 code might have a great idea that makes your hacks irrelevant or actually slower than straightforward code. Joe Armstrong, the Erlang guy, always tells people to just "write the most beautiful code you can". Slow code is almost always an algorithmic problem anyway.